# How can I tell when Ubuntu 16.04 has finished formatting a USB?

Tags: 16.04, usb, nautilus

I just formatted a USB directly from nautilus, but once I'd chosen the conditions, the USB disappeared from the menu and no window has opened to display the progress or completion.

I see in the system that monitors that the CPU and the disk are working, but I do not know when the USB is fully formatted.

**update:**

Ok, now I opened GNOME Disks and I saw this

[image: Disks view of the USB]

Comment: Please can you properly explain your situation? Possibly include some screenshots of the problem , so that we can help you to solve it

Comment: @KuntalMajumder   I did start formatting the USB stick, but nothing happened, I do not know if he has finished formatting. I would not remove the USB while formatting.

Comment: Did you try GParted to format it? I believe you could get more information about.

Comment: @gwarah  Yes of course! I'm asking if this is a nautilus bug... or if it is a my problem!

Comment: Ok. First of all, are your ubuntu up to dated? If no, please update. Then: open a terminal, type nautilus and try to format again your USB. Please, pick the terminal output and post in your question. You could also post  the system [nautilus log](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles).

Comment: I've also found a [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302120/how-can-i-debug-nautilus-crashes) and a [Wiki topic](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingGNOME) that maybe can help you.

Comment: @gwarah thanks for the tips, but there isn't any output in the terminal, and i don't have found the nautilus log...

Comment: It's true @PatrickBarattin! Sounds really strange an important ubuntu app like this doesn't have any debug output method (log or command key)! Well, some things to do: You may install another file manager and try to do the same, so you can know if the problem comes from nautilus or ubuntu component. I think you also should open a ticket on [ubuntu lanchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu) relating this issue.  Hope It can help you ;)

Comment: @PatrickBarattin Your update looks like an answer to me. Self answering is actually [encouraged here.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18067/reputation-requirement-for-a-self-answer) I highly recommend that you [edit] your answer out of the update to your question and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 16.04 does not show any information while it's formatting a pendrive from the file explorer window. Just leave it plugged in until the light stops blinking, and then some more (for good measure).

Comment: or from an application like Gparted or Disks

Answer (score 3):

The device name goes away until the format is finished. Once the format has finished the device name comes back. So when you start a format in Nautilus, especially when you want the data zero'd out, do not close Nautilus until you see the device name again. I just formatted a 8 Gb USB drive and it took about 10 minutes to complete.