# I can't see external storage device formatting progress

Tags: external-hdd, disk-formatting

30 minutes ago I plugged in an external storage device and asked Ubuntu to format it. After I made this query, Ubuntu closed the window I was in and doesn't show anything related to the formatting process (I was expecting a progress bar or something like that).

I tried to shut down and restart Ubuntu, but without success. Then I thought that Ubuntu refused to shut down or restart the computer because maybe the formatting is happening in the background somehow. Right now my external drive is blinking, which may mean that this is being formatted, but I'm not sure.

How can I see if the formatting process is happening when there is no progress bar showing up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I just found a way to track the formatting progress in Ubuntu:

1. I opened the Terminal.
2. Then I ran:

   ```
   sudo gnome-disks
   ```
3. The Disks application opened, and then I selected the external drive in the left list. The progress bar is now appearing in the *Work* section.

Reference:

- [How can I tell when Ubuntu 16.04 has finished formatting a USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813431/how-can-i-tell-when-ubuntu-16-04-has-finished-formatting-a-usb)

Comment: I'm using 18.04 and searched for "Disks" in my Applications and it came up. Thanks!